# TCL/TK, MS Access or PS as front end for sqlite?

Tags: powershell, ms-access, sqlite, tcl, frontend

To allow also other person to make queries or changes I would like to know which front end/GUI would be suitable for sqlite-database. Due to restrictions given by our IT-administration I have only a reduced choice of programs. Surprisingly, I could install TCL (why?).

My question: Does it makes sense to use TCL/TK as front end for sqlite?  Or are there reasons not to use TCL?
Alternatives would be MS Access as front end connected to sqlite via ODBC. Another could be Power Shell. My preference is TCL or PS since I don't like to work with GUI-tools. Any other suggestions?
OS is Windows 7.

---

Background:
I developed an sqlite database to administrate members of our little institute (members, students, adresse, courses, etc.). My assistant and I are the only two persons who know sql and can make changes (selects, updates and inserts). Before, this administration was done with 30 Excels and 50 sheets. We succeeded to import the data within a reasonable relational database model. Important: I'm not a professional programmer but the only person in this institute who has a little porgramming knowledge (Perl, SQL, R) and who likes to learn more.

The reason we used sqlite was that our institute is embedded in a big hospital with centralized IT-service and a very strict IT-policy. So, I can't install MySQL and PHP due to restrictions. I could use MS-Access which is installed in every client but I found the developement with sqlite and batch-files (dos) easier since I don't like to use GUI and I don't know VBA. My preferred working environment (for programming) is dos-terminal to run scripts and emacs to write programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl can talk to SQLite just fine; the interface for doing so is documented on the [SQLite main site](https://sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html), one of the few languages for which this is true.

> The SQLite library is designed to be very easy to use from a Tcl or Tcl/Tk script. SQLite began as a Tcl extension and the primary test suite for SQLite is written in TCL. SQLite can be used with any programming language, but its connections to TCL run deep.

Tcl also works well on Windows 7. I used to use it quite a bit on that exact platform.

There are options for doing a highly-locked-down deployment which might be interesting to you, where the entire runtime is packaged into a single file. (You'll probably be best finding out more about them by asking on `comp.lang.tcl`; access via Google Groups.) There are also (commercial) options for encrypted SQLite databases.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I was aware about the SQLite main site but I was not sure how reliable this information is since on the net tcl/sqlite is not very present. Obviously, TCL/sqlite is used and that motivates me to choose TCL.